# Is there a python function that would allow me to add an extra layer to cross tab?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a table that would imitate the following table from excel.
[image]

My Data is:
Col1    Col2    Col3
A   Red Cheetah
A   Red Cheetah
A   Red Cheetah
A   Blue    Cheetah
A   Blue    Cheetah
A   Blue    Cheetah
A   Blue    Cheetah
A   Blue    Cheetah
B   Blue    Cheetah
B   Blue    Cheetah
C   Blue    Cheetah
C   Blue    Cheetah
C   Blue    Lion
C   Blue    Lion
C   Orange  Lion
C   Orange  Lion
A   Orange  Lion
A   Orange  Lion
A   Orange  Lion
A   Orange  Lion
A   Red Lion
A   Red Lion
A   Red Bear
A   Red Bear
A   Red Bear
B   Red Bear
B   Green   Bear
B   Green   Bear
C   Green   Bear
C   Green   Bear
C   Green   Bear

I tried separating the data frame into smaller data frames based on the col3 but I would like it all to still be one table as pictured above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
df = pd.crosstab(
    index=[df.Col1, df.Col3],
    columns=df.Col2,
    rownames=["Row Labels", "Column Labels"],
    colnames=["Count of Col1"],
    margins=True,
    margins_name="Grand Total"
)

print(df)
```

OutPut:

```
Count of Col1              Blue  Green  Orange  Red  Grand Total
Row Labels  Column Labels                                       
A           Bear              0      0       0    3            3
            Cheetah           5      0       0    3            8
            Lion              0      0       4    2            6
B           Bear              0      2       0    1            3
            Cheetah           2      0       0    0            2
C           Bear              0      3       0    0            3
            Cheetah           2      0       0    0            2
            Lion              2      0       2    0            4
Grand Total                  11      5       6    9           31
```

Comment: Is there anyway to add the subtotal percentages for each item in Col1?

Answer (score 0):

Read your data from excel to python using [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).
Then create pivot table using [pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). There are decent examples in the docs that look just like your problem. Good luck.